# Wrong page count in PDF files

Tags: c#, regex, itext

I am using `iTextSharp` in my C# application. PDF reader gives error:

> The document has no page root (meaning: it's an invalid PDF).

Then we again try to fetch count property using below regex:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.pdf")))
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");                
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd());
    Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
}
```

But using this regex we get double count..(i.e if actual file has 6 count this regext returns count as 12)

Any solution to get page for this kind of files ?

I can not share file as it is client provided file.
On future verification on file content, i found below matches for regex:

```
/Type /XObject 
/Type /Page 
/Type /Catalog 
/Type /XObject 
/Type /Pages 
/Type /Page 
/Type /XObject 
/Type /Pages 
/Type /Page 
/Type /XObject 
/Type /Pages 
/Type /Page 
/Type /XObject 
/Type /Pages 
/Type /Page 
/Type /XObject 
/Type /Pages 
/Type /Page 
%PaperPortPDFversion1 0 obj<</Contents 10 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 2 0 R/Resources 9 0 R/Rotate 180/Type/Page>>
12 0 obj<</Contents 20 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 16 0 R/Resources 19 0 R/Rotate 180/Type/Page>>
21 0 obj<</Contents 29 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 25 0 R/Resources 28 0 R/Rotate 180/Type/Page>>
30 0 obj<</Contents 38 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 34 0 R/Resources 37 0 R/Rotate 180/Type/Page>>
39 0 obj<</Contents 47 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 43 0 R/Resources 46 0 R/Rotate 180/Type/Page>>
48 0 obj<</Contents 56 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 52 0 R/Resources 55 0 R/Rotate 180/Type/Page>>
```

Because of last matches it gives double count then actual.(i.e 12 count instead 6 count)

Is there any solution for solving this kind of file,as this is file specific issue not with all file.

Thanks

Comment: Please format your question properly, place only code in the code block.

Comment: try https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this the case for alle PDF files, or only your **test.pdf**? Could it be possible that the regex matches something in the body text of the document as well (e.g. Table of contents)?

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? BTW, the regex variant only works under certain assumptions concerning the PDF's internals which fairly often are true but by far not always.

Comment: Just remove the * from the regex behind the \s and the last lines wont match anymore

Comment: @prizm1 Unfortunately there may be any number of spaces between those two PDF names in a PDF, starting at 0. Thus, your proposal might return the correct number of pages for this document but would return a false result for others.

Comment: @Viral While I can only guess, it looks like the PDF in question contains at least two revisions, and the latter one contains updates of the page dictionaries of the former one (e.g. for adding `/Rotate 180` to correct orientation if the original PDF pages were upside-down). One of the *assumptions concerning the PDF's internals* inherent in that regex is that there are no such incremental updates...

Comment: @Viral I assume you use a current iTextSharp version, i.e. 7.0.x or at least 5.5.9. If the `PdfReader` of such a current version returns an error, chances are very high the PDF indeed is broken. As you cannot share the PDF file in question, we cannot finally verify that, though.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for information, is there any possibility of giving this file to you for verification using secure mail ?

Comment: There is an email address in my profile here. If you send something there, please also comment here because i only poll that account when i expect mail.

Comment: @mkl, i have sent you mail for the client pdf file having issue.

Comment: The mail has not yet arrived. Is there probably a mail filter? In the time since several mails came in. Thus, I'd assume things are ok on my side.